# String can't be coerced into Fixnum Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby, and was tasked with creating a simple program that grabs user input, and then uses an elsif statement to give a possible 3 different answers. Here's my code:

```
print "What is your birth year?"
year = gets.chomp
age = 2016 - year
 if age >= 40
     puts "You're old!"
 elsif age.between?(25, 39)
    puts "You aren't too old!"
 else
    puts "You're just a baby!"
end
```

However, I keep getting "String can't be coerced into Fixnum"

I don't recall in the lessons doing something like I'm doing for the "age" variable, so I could be doing it wrong, but I also couldn't find an answer in my lessons or online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll find that it'll make your coding life easier if you keep your code indented properly. Any decent text editor will make that easy. In your code notice that your `if age >= 40` is indented, along with the rest of the associated block, but the closing `end` is not. In code with more complex nesting, or with class or method definitions that would make debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `gets` returns a string value, and in Ruby strings and numeric values are completely different things. Some other languages will coerce them as necessary, like PHP, Perl or JavaScript, but Ruby does not.

To make this work:

```
year = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Although technically `to_i` alone is usually sufficient.

Comment: Oh my god. I can't thank you enough right now. That was driving me crazy!

Comment: It's a little perplexing for someone used to the auto-conversion. In Ruby land `"5" == 5` returns `false`. Also `0` is logically true, so watch out!